# Avoiding recursion with RxJS5 in simple use case

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, rxjs5

I am trying to figure out how to avoid recursion (if possible). I am using RxJS to create methods on a queue. The drain method calls itself recursively, if the queue is not empty. The drain method is currently designed to remove one item at a time from the queue, until it's empty. The following seems to work for this purpose, but I'd like to find out if it's possible to avoid calling drain recursively. The problem with recursion is that I probably cannot "return" any items from the resursive method until it's done recursing (that's my guess).

So my question is:

I want the subscriber of drain() to receive each item from the queue separately, instead of receiving all drained items from the queue at once when the method is done recursing. How can I accomplish that? Can I accomplish this with a recursive method, or perhaps I can only accomplish this with a non-recursive method? If the latter, how to do that?

> this method will drain the queue, and stop trying when the queue is
>   empty we need to lock, remove an item, then unlock, every time, so
>   it's easiest to just use recursion and re-call the drain method if the
>   queue is not empty

```
Queue.prototype.drain = function (opts) {

    opts = opts || {};
    const delay = opts.delay || 500;

    return this.init()
        .flatMap(() => {
            return acquireLock(this)
                .flatMap(obj => {
                    return acquireLockRetry(obj)
                });
        })
        .flatMap(obj => {
            return removeOneLine(this)
                .flatMap(l => {
                    return releaseLock(this, obj.id)
                        .map(obj => l);
                });
        })
        .flatMap(() => {
            return Rx.Observable.timer(delay)
                .flatMap(() => {
                    return this.drain()   /// <<< recurse
                        .takeUntil(this.isEmpty());  /// <<<< until
                });
        })
        .catch(e => {
            const force = !String(e.stack || e).match(/acquire lock timed out/);
            return releaseLock(this, force);
        });

};
```

> // check if the queue is empty

```
Queue.prototype.isEmpty = function () {

    return this.init()
        .flatMap(() => {
            return acquireLock(this)
                .flatMap(obj => {
                    return acquireLockRetry(obj)
                })
        })
        .flatMap(obj => {
            return findFirstLine(this)
                .flatMap(l => {
                    return releaseLock(this, obj.id)
                        .map(obj => l);
                });
        })
        .filter(l => {
            // filter out any lines => only fire event if there is no line
            return !l;
        })
        .catch(e => {
            const force = !String(e.stack || e).match(/acquire lock timed out/);
            return releaseLock(this, force);
        });

};
```

Comment: Recursion is the way to go most of the time. Why not use a break by using a `callback` that you pass into the `drain()`?

Comment: Yeah, I have no real problem with recursion, just that in this case I may not be able to emit events until after it's done. I guess firing a callback that's passed in would work. I suppose they could also just pass in an RxJS observer too, instead of a plain cb (?).

Comment: What about the `acquireLock`, `releaseLock` and `isEmpty`, `findFirstLine` is asynchronous? Are you reading from a file or network resource, or is it distributed? If neither of those things, I think Rx might be overkill in this case.

Comment: all of those methods are asynchronous, I don't think there is a single method in the queue that is synchronous. the queue lives on disk, not in memory, and the locking mechanism is networked, because multiple processes might read from the queue on disk. You could do this w/o RxJS, like anything, but RxJS might be helpful, just want to learn it, this is a good excuse to do so. A queue is a neverending set of values so good use case for Rx.

Comment: Trust me I am not so masochistic that I would try to use RxJS for a bunch of  synchronous calls :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution to the problem is something like this:

```
    const obs = new Rx.Subject();

    q.drain(obs).subscribe(function (v) {
        console.log('end result => ', v);
    });

    obs.subscribe(function (v) {
        console.log('next item that was drained => ', v);
    });
```

and the drain method just becomes:

```
Queue.prototype.drain = function (obs, opts) {

    opts = opts || {};

    const delay = opts.delay || 500;

    return this.init()
        .flatMap(() => {
            return acquireLock(this)
                .flatMap(obj => {
                    console.log(' drain lock id => ', obj.id);
                    return acquireLockRetry(obj)
                });
        })
        .flatMap(obj => {
            return removeOneLine(this)
                .flatMap(l => {
                    return releaseLock(this, obj.id)
                        .map(obj => {
                            obs.next(l);
                            return l;
                        });
                });
        })
        .flatMap(() => {
            return Rx.Observable.timer(500)
                .flatMap(() => {
                    return this.drain(obs, opts)
                        .takeUntil(this.isEmpty());
                });
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.error('\n', ' => isEmpty() error => \n', e.stack || e);
            const force = !String(e.stack || e).match(/acquire lock timed out/);
            return releaseLock(this, force);
        });

};
```

in this way, everytime an item is removed, it will fire something, and then hopefully fire an event at the very end, when the queue is completely drained.